# postgresql: delete from table1 using table 2 where doesn't work as expected

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

table1:

```
"table1_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"table1_user_id" btree (user_id)
"table1_active" btree (bool_to_int(active))
...
Referenced by:
    TABLE "table2" CONSTRAINT "my_id" FOREIGN KEY (my_id) REFERENCES table1(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

table2:

```
"table2_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"table2_my_id" btree (my_id)
...
"my_id" FOREIGN KEY (my_id) REFERENCES table1(id) 
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

I'm trying to perform the following statement:

```
delete from table2 using table1 where user_id = 3
  and my_id = any(array[1, 2, 3])
```

What do I expect:

1. table2 and table1 are joined using a foreign key my_id <-> id
2. Rows with user_id = 3 from table1 and all the my_ids from given array from table2 are selected for delete.
3. Rows are deleted.

However, what happens is that this statement deletes all the rows which pass on part of the condition with my_id = any(array[1, 2, 3]) completely ignoring the user_id = 3 part. Causing a delete of records of other users.

So the question is: why does delete with using clause is not working as expected? What am I missing?

I already figured out a more simple solution to this problem which seem to be working as expected:

```
delete from table2 where my_id in (select my_id from table2 join table1 on table1.id = alert_id where user_id = 3 and my_id = any(array[1, 2, 3]))
```

But the original question still remains.

Comment: "table2 and table1 are joined using a foreign key my_id <-> id"  You have to put that join condition into your WHERE clause.  It won't get supplied automatically, just as it doesn't get supplied automatically in a SELECT.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solution you provided fixed my query.